# Expandable divs

Tags: css

I'm having a problem figuring out how to get **div 4** to stay the same position when **div 1** expands. All the divs are floating left and when I expand **div 1** to expand **div 2** also expands leaving an empty space between 2 and 4.

I can't wrap **div 1, 3** and **div 2, 4** in separate divs

[image: example]

This is the style I use for the divs:

```
 .subcatagory {
    float: left;
    width: 150px;
 }
```

Comment: which browsers would you to support?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a problem with **float**. For this you have to use [Js masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/) . Other then you have to define your markup like this:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="long">1</div>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
<div class="parent">
    <div>2</div>
    <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/XhMtK/1/

Comment: Thanks it works perfectly. Is it supported by every browser though?

Comment: Yes, It's support every browser

Answer (score 2):

The following will do what you're looking for. I wrapped all the original divs in an outter div setting its width so that it can only fit 2. Then I classified two divs, category (div1 and div3 fall under this class) and subcategory which float right and left of each other. Here's some code to demonstrate:

```
   <html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css">
    #dvMain{
     width:305px;

    }

    .subcategory, .category{
      width: 150px;
      border:solid black 1px
    }

    .subcategory{
     float: right;
    }

    .category {
    float: left;
    }
  </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="dvMain">
    <div id="dv1" class="category">1asadssadsad
    sadsa
    ds
    adsad
    sa
    dsadsadsadsa
    </div>
    <div id="dv2" class="subcategory">2</div>
    <div id="dv4" class="subcategory">4</div>
    <div id="dv3" class="category">3</div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```